# Alfresco get the path of documents using CMIS

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I'm trying to fetch document objects from Alfresco Community edition,I need the documents path, while i use

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:document where ''
```

but i thing the cmis:document namespace doesn't return the path, i was wondering if there is a way to include the path.
PS : i can only use JAVASCRIPT with cmis queries

Comment: Do you want the result to contain path (like it contains other metadata), or do you want to search by path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a CMIS query you should just fetch the object by URL using its object ID, then grab the path. The browser binding, which is easily invocable from JavaScript, supports this.

For example, suppose I have a file named "test-1.txt" sitting in a folder called "/test" with an Alfresco object ID of:

```
workspace://SpacesStore/1fb2d9cf-11ca-47c2-94b4-cf72de8f9b92
```

I can use this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/root?objectId=workspace://SpacesStore/1fb2d9cf-11ca-47c2-94b4-cf72de8f9b92&cmisselector=parents&includerelativepathsegment=true
```

To return JSON that includes:

```
{
    "id": "cmis:path",
    "localName": "path",
    "displayName": "Path",
    "queryName": "cmis:path",
    "type": "string",
    "cardinality": "single",
    "value": "\/test"
}
```

Which contains the path.

You can shorten up the JSON significantly by also adding "&succinct=true"

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to write your own Javascript backed web script. It's controller would find the node using CMIS query, and it's FTL would actually display the path in any format you like.

https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6243-50-javascript-api
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/API-JS-ScriptNode.html

Comment: Agreed that this would work, but the OP specified the requirement to use only JavaScript with CMIS queries, which I took to mean client-side JavaScript talking to CMIS endpoints only, not custom web scripts.